# DataTable & Bindingsource unable to cast

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, filtering, bindingsource

I am trying to make a multiple criteria filter in my datagridview using datatable. Only problem is to convert gridview to table, and was trying more answers found here and MSDN forums. It is still not working and now I'm stuck.
Here is my full method:

```
  public void updateText(string txt, string txt2, string txt3)         
  {
        myform = null;
        var bs = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        var table = (DataTable)bs.DataSource;
        table.Select("Azonosito Like '%" + txt + "%' AND Név Like '%" + txt2 + "%'");
        label4.Text = "Lefutott";  //just for debugging reasons to see if it runs
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
  }
```

Azonosisto an Név are cloumn headers. txt3 is currently not used, might need it in the future, all filter texts came from another form using this method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the DataBind method.
I think that if you add this line in the end (after you assign the data source) it should work.

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```